# Getting [object Object] instead of value in protractor getText()

Tags: protractor

I am trying expect the value like
var foo = element(by.name('salutId'));
expect(foo.getText()).toEqual('MS');

```
    console.log(foo); -- shows like [object Object]
    Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, *[name="salutId"])
```

Comment: Can you please share more details about the code, language used and logic ?

Answer (score 1):

.getText() returns a promise. Promise is on object. Thus what you see is expected

In order to resolve a promise and get the value, you should use either `await` or `.then`

While first syntax is recommended, I'll show you an example with the second

```
foo.getText().then(value => {
  console.log(value)
  expect(value).toEqual('MS');
)
```